# How do you make a redirect to an 'admin LTE' template in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've been following a tutorial on addition of an admin LTE template to a Laravel site. The previous version of Laravel used in the tutorial, the file `\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` has

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
```

whereas the version I am using has

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

When I used both statements, after login, the site loaded my admin page as expected. Is it advisable to use both `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;` and  `protected $redirectTo = '/admin';` ?
If not, how do I write a redirect to my admin panel that will use a statement like this one:

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

Comment: Both ways are fine and serve the same purpose. The later version abstracted the home route in a service provider which makes it accessible in more than one places.

Answer (score 1):

The both way are right but more efficient way is to use like abstraction method as per your view.

```
**protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;**
```

The reason of if you are using partial routing system then it will more helpfull  the abstraction system via RouteServiceProvider.

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Providers;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
       
        protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
    
        protected $adminNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin';
    
        protected $adminRedirect = '/admin/home';
    
        protected $userRedirect = '/home';
    }
```

> Now I'm easily maintain and good to understand.